# Fedora 17 : Cannot open font file True

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2, fonts

Each time I login to Fedora 17, no GUI, just a console, I notice this error:

```
Cannot open font file True
```

I have followed some tutorial on web to fix this problem, but still cannot. Here some steps that I have done:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`

   `vi /etc/default/grub`. After that, change `SYSFONT=True` to `SYSFONT=atarcyrheb-sun16`
2. Edit `/etc/sysconfig/i18n`. Same, change `SYSFONT=True` to `SYSFONT=atarcyrheb-sun16`
3. Rebuild Grub2 with the command `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

In my boot folder, I don't have a grub2 directory. I must create it first with
`mkdir /boot/grub2`

But no matter how I try, I still meet this frustrating error. When I boot to recovering mode, I see a failed operation : `failed to mount /media/sda8`. Does it matter to my error?

Comment: As I see the same "missing font" (is True a flag to use some default?), the mounting problem seems to be unrelated. See [Redhat/Fedora Bug 799401](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=799401)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by setting the font with:

```
SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16
```